# Restart singleTask Activity

Tags: android

i write launcher activity that have option to show or hide wallpaper to do that i use two theme

> android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

and

> android:Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar

to change it i do

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Utils.PrintInfo("MainActivity.onNewIntent");


    if (AppSettings.Data.WallpaperThemeChanged) {
        AppSettings.Data.WallpaperThemeChanged = false;


        startActivity(new Intent(this, ThemeReloadActivity.class));

        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

with `ThemeReloadActivity` like this

```
public class ThemeReloadActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Utils.PrintError("ThemeReloadActivity.onCreate");

    Activity activity = MainActivity.getMainActivity();
    activity.finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

and this is my Manifest fragment for that activity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.maxcom.launcher.MainActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

but sometimes if i spam home theme does not change, it looks like app does not restart at all

Comment: Do you want to restart the total application or only one activity??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can restart your application by the following code

```
Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: yea i try it but when i realize i can not restart application, i have to restart single activity would be best to do it in background but how can i achive this

Comment: To restart only one activity you can use "recreate()" method.

Comment: Thanks, It helped...(y)

Answer (score 0):

```
        // get rid of this activity instance and start a new one
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyApp.getInstance(), MyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only restart activity you can do this

```
this.recreate();
```

this will recreate your activity.